# Pass a parameter to an application invocation in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm basically trying to simplify this snippet:

```
if($includeSecondOption) {
    MyApplication --someOption --anotherOption
}
else {
    MyApplication --someOption
}
```

To a one-liner... but I'm not sure if it's possible. The variable `$appendEmailSuffix` is a boolean. I'm not sure how to google for this either.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to use splatting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6 Put your options in an array and then you splat the array into the command arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:

```
if ($includeSecondOption) ? MyApplication --someOption --anotherOption : MyApplication --someOption
```

Comment: It's basically the same... I can also write the if/else in the same line. I'm looking for a way to not duplicate the `MyApplication` line but kind of apply the ternary operator only on the option part.

Comment: I think I miss understood your query, can you elaborate a bit please

Comment: Probably take a look at the solution suggested by Duncan